# How to display references two deep in phoenix elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am wanting to display a reference two tables deep in Pheonix Elixirr, and seem one step away from actually getting it.

There are three interrelated tables:

The main table is Clients. Clients have Requests. Requests have Requesttypes, which are a lookup table.

In the Clients Template would like to show a listing of the requests a client has made. In the Show Template, there is a loop as follows:

```
  <ul>
     <%= for request <- @client.requests do %>

       <%= request.request_date %> - 
       <line in question> -
       <%= request.notes %>&nbsp;

       <%= link "Show", to: Routes.client_request_path(@conn, :show, @client, request) %>&nbsp;
       <%= link "Edit", to: Routes.client_request_path(@conn, :edit, @client, request) %>
     <% end %>
  </ul>
```

The above is working fine without the line in question. I would like to add the request type, which is selected from a dropdown, so a reference from the Request table.

If I try to add:
`<%= request.requesttype.requestname =>`
It doesn't work.

In the Request Show page
`<%= @requesttype.requestname =>`
does work

And in the line in question
`<%= request.requesttype_id %>`
Does show the correct id.

The error is `key :requesttype not found in: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :requesttypes is not loaded>.`

The get_client function is as follows:

```
def get_client!(id, tenant) do 
Client 
|> Repo.get!(id, prefix: Triplex.to_prefix(tenant)) 
|> Repo.preload([:genders, :requests]) 
end
```

How would I add association from the requests table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couple of questions :) What error did you get exactly? How did you query (did you use some [`preload`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3))? Can you try to replace the following: `<%= for request <- @client.requests |> IO.inspect(label: "requests") do %>` and see what is being logged?

Comment: The error is ```key :requesttype not found in: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :requesttypes is not loaded>```. Seems that the associations from the Requests table are not being loaded. How do I preload those? Here is the get_client function: 
```  def get_client!(id, tenant) do
    Client
    |> Repo.get!(id, prefix: Triplex.to_prefix(tenant))
    |> Repo.preload([:genders, :requests])
  end
```

Comment: I added these into the main body of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by the error message, the nested `requesttypes` are not loaded because you are only preloading `client.requests`, but not the associated `requesttypes`. You need to be explicit about what you are preloading, which is actually a good thing because you are controlling what you are querying.

Using `Repo.preload([genders: [], requests: :requesttypes])` should fix your issue, it is using a keyword list to preload nested associations as in [one of these doc examples](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:preload/3-examples).

Please note that this will fire 4 separate queries (which might be fine or not depending on your use case), if you want to use joins to avoid this you should probably write a query (see [this great explanation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#preload/3)).

I encourage you to fiddle with your queries in the REPL (`iex -S mix`), it is very transparent and you'll see:

- the data being returned (what is loaded or not)
- the underlying queries from the debug log

There is a [great section](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/ecto/querying/#querying-for-associated-data) about this in Elixir school that could be interesting as well.

Comment: thank you very much. The preload with the nested associationns were just the thing. Thanks for the links to creating joins and the associated data.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it worked! If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept the answer for further references ;)

Comment: @ArniMikelsons please mark the answer as correct with the green checkmark in the top-left corner. It’s mandatory according to SO rules. Thanks.